# How to access variables defined in method with require_once

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop

I've been working on a simple class that kindo build on the MVC framework. I'm trying to learn a lot about programming. I'm having a problem with scope. It has quite a simple PHP script and need access a variable `birth`.

```
class NUMK {

    public $plugin_name;
    public $version;

    public function __construct( $plugin_name, $version) {

        $this->plugin_name = $plugin_name;
        $this->version = $version;
        $this->loadClient();

    }

    public function pager(){
        if(isset($_POST['birth'])){
            $birth = $_POST['birth'];
            require_once '/html/view/index.php';
        };

    }

}
```

How can I access `$birth` in `/html/view/index.php`. I tried `global $birth`. No luck.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you would have to call the require before you try to access the variable. But that's not the big problem here, the problem is when you run that function it's going to include the entire '/html/view/index.php' page where you call it. Unless that's what you're going for.

Comment: yea i want that, the page is `html` and `NUMK` class is logic

Comment: So `$birth` is first defined in `index.php` and you're trying to change the value with the method??  Or are you defining `$birth` in the method and then trying to use in `index.php`

Comment: @WheatBeak second option.

Comment: Is your require working at all? It could be a path issue.  Are you running this locally or on a webserver?

Comment: Also, `$_POST` is a superglobal, could you just access it on the `index.php` instead of assigning it to `$birth` in the method?

Comment: @WheatBeak no i need to modifies it before the view.

Comment: `$birth` should be available in `index.php` using this approach. Are you getting a particular error that indicates that it's undefined, or is this just indicated by some missing effect?

Comment: its just null. I try and `var_dump($birth)` and `null` is returned. Thats in `index.php` of course. I used the bellow answer and it worked but I don't think its a safe option.

Comment: What if you modify the value and just save it back to `$_POST`

Comment: @WheatBeak ah all these are hacky solution, should i just be able to access the variables in the includes `index.php` ?.

Comment: Theoretically you should be able to, I don't understand why it's not working.  Can you update your question to include the code where you're calling the method, and the area of the `index.php` where you're trying to access the variable.  If it's not too much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [extract function](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.extract.php). It receives an array and import variables into the current symbol table, after that you can reference it in the required file, as $birth.

Example:

```php
public function pager(){
    if(isset($_POST['birth'])){
        $data          = array();
        $data['birth'] = $_POST['birth'];
        extract($data, EXTR_REFS);
        require_once '/html/view/index.php';
    };

}
```

Comment: is that the only way? seems hacky//

Comment: Indeed it seems hacky, but it's the way some MVC frameworks exposes variables created at Controllers to the Views. Seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Yea your right, Is this secure tho? any more info it, about never hear of it, would like to read about it.

Comment: also its super strange functionality. if I create any varable like `$testingB`, even if I dont add it to $data is still availabe in the `view/index.php`, what the hell?

Comment: it's a common use for exposing a variable between files.. Laravel/FuelPHP are examples of frameworks tha uses this approach 

https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.8/develop/classes/view.php#L236
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php#L36